# Why does Rabin Karp algorithm need 2 hash functions for the pattern string? (and also for the substring)

Tags: algorithm, rabin-karp

For example, we have string1:"AB" which must be found in string2:"CABA". 
For string1 h1=('A'*27 + 'B') and h2=('A'*29 + 'B'), and for string2 we calculate the hash1 and hash2 functions (h2.1='C'*27 + 'A', h2.2='C'*29 + 'C') and we compare the results with string1's hash functions.

I do not understand why we need 2 hash functions with different bases for every string or substring.

Comment: This doesn't sound like Rabin-Karp to me. You need a rolling hash where given the hash of  patter[n..m] you can computer pattern[n+1...m+1] in constant time from it.

Answer (score 1):

Having two different hash functions reduces the probability of a collision, but a version with one hash function also works(we don't always need the second function).